# Dot in regular expression (regex)

Tags: c, regex

I am using slre (https://code.google.com/p/slre/) for providing a regex library for a c program.

I want to match an IP address with following pattern: `"^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$"`

I get following compile error: Warning: unknown excape sequence '\.'
I also tried it with '\\.' --> the compile error is gone, but it's still saying it doesn't match.

```
   if (!slre_compile(&slre, settings[i].regex)) {
       printf("Error compiling RE: %s\n", slre.err_str);
   } 
   else if (!slre_match(&slre, settings[i].value, strlen(settings[i].value), captures)) {
       printf("\nSetting '%s' does not match the regular expression!", settings[i].internName);
   }
```

settings[i].regex is a char* with the regular expression I mentioned above
settings[i].value is a char*
the string I am trying to match is 8.8.8.8

Is there any other way to check for a dot?

Comment: Putting special characters in a character class (in your case `[.]`) is considered a best practice.

Comment: `\.` in a regex is the correct way to check for a dot, `\\.` is the correct way to represent that in a C string.  Please provide the code where you attempt the match.

Comment: That matches an IPv4 address, not URL.

Comment: You need two backslashes, one to escape the following backslash in the C string literal, and one to escape the `.` for the regular expression engine. Please show us the string that it's failing to match.

Comment: okay I added the information you guys requested, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `[.]`

Dot isn't special inside character class.

Answer (score 4):

The C compiler is seeing your backslash as an attempt to escape a character in C, in the same way that `\n` becomes a newline.  You need to use a double-backslash:

```
\\.
```

The C compiler will turn that into a single backslash and pass that to the regex library.

That's the source of the compiler warning - if it's still not matching after you add the extra backslash then you have a different problem as well.

According to http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx your regex does match `8.8.8.8`, so the problem isn't with the regex itself.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is about C, but if you can compile with C++11 you can have a look to literal raw string

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2442.htm

```
std::string literal_string = R"literal string\. \n";
```